# Call to a member function update() on null with array/checkbox/edit

Tags: laravel

Need help here i m trying to take values from checkbox s and put them into a edit to change the value "Estado" to "Expedido" but when I run the code it gives me the error"Call to a member function update() on null".I also tried find and change the default of find() to the column i want and also tried with raw postgresql code.

```
        $chassis= $request->chassis;
    $escala = $request->escala;
    if(Auth::check() == true)
    {
       
        foreach($chassis as $chassis)
        {
            $edit = expedicoes::whereIn('Chassis', explode(',',$chassis))->first()->update(['Estado' =>'Expedido']);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `update(Array)` doesnt exist on a model instance, it only exists on a query builder as a Builder instance.

either remove the `first()` call to call update on the query builder

```
$edit = expedicoes::whereIn('Chassis', explode(',',$chassis))->update(['Estado' =>'Expedido']);
```

Or update the on the model then call `save()`

```
$edit = expedicoes::whereIn('Chassis', explode(',',$chassis))->first();
if ($edit) {
    $edit->Estado = 'Expedido';
    $edit->save();
}
```

I suggest you remove the update call from the foreach loop, gather all "chassis" and run a single query

```
$extractedChassis = [];
foreach($chassis as $chassi)
{
    $extractedChassis = array_merge($extractedChassis , explode(',',$chassi));
}
expedicoes::whereIn('Chassis', $extractedChassis)->update(['Estado' =>'Expedido']);
```

Comment: Still says the same error

Comment: @GustavoAguiar which one give you which error ? provided you with 3 solutions.

Comment: Ok sorry in the first 2 gives the same error the third gives "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".

Comment: @GustavoAguiar that is because you use the same variable in your foreach loop `foreach($chassis as $chassis)` just change the second variable as shown in the 3rd example. But the 3rd example should be more performant in your case.

Comment: It runs but i doesn t change the value.

Comment: @GustavoAguiar do a `dd($extractedChassis)` before the update and check if the format is as it should be. but that should be in another question by itself with more details like your HTML code and your Database structure. The original issue of this question is answered.

Comment: `array:2 [▼
  0 => "chassis[PX421]"
  1 => "chassis[PX991]"
]`

Comment: @GustavoAguiar You are not sending the data correctly, please post another question with the HTML/blade used to Generate the checkboxes.

Comment: @GustavoAguiar you can join me in this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245891/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-72745786-call-to-a-member-function-update-on if you want it resolved quickly, or post a question.

Answer (score 0):

this code return null

```
expedicoes::whereIn('Chassis', explode(',',$chassis))->first()
```

so you have no items that Chassis in `explode(',',$chassis)`

to solve this you can check if its not return null then update it

```
 $expedicoes = expedicoes::whereIn('Chassis', explode(',',$chassis))->first();
if(expedicoes ){
expedicoes ->update(['Estado' =>'Expedido']);
}
```

but i think your problem in column name so try to use **chassis** instead of *Chassis*
and **estado** instead of *Estado*

Comment: ok i allready changed but it doesn t change the "Estado".

Comment: you need to check if $expedicoes  return an object not null;
if it returns null you need to check explode(',',$chassis) return  not empty array